# Count distinct elements and return only one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with many integers in column named 'data'

```
data  |  param

123      1
432      1
123      1
423      2
234      1
423      2
```

I have a query

```
SELECT data FROM data_table WHERE param=*something* GROUP BY data
    ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

That returns a random distinct integer from the table. But I also need to get the total number of integers that I was choosing from. I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(data) AS data, COUNT(DISTINCT(data)) as count FROM
    data_table WHERE param=*something* ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

This returns correct number from which data was chosen, but the *data* returned is no random - it is always the same row. So I need to get number of rows that rand() were selected after WHERE was applied. So making a query on above table should return:

```
query WHERE param='1':
    data  count
    123   3
query WHERE param='1':
    data  count
    432   3
query WHERE param='1':
    data  count
    234   3
query WHERE param='2':
    data  count
    423   1
```

Comment: give example of the result you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works.  I normally don't recommend putting a query in the selector because it evaluates for each row returned.  However in this case you are only returning one row so it is OK.

```
select 
count(distinct data) as cnt,
(SELECT data FROM data_table GROUP BY data
    WHERE param='xxx'
    ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) as random
from data_table
WHERE param='xxx'
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0fa0/6) to see it work without the where statements.

Comment: Be sure that the data column has an index or is covered an an existing index.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest is to join another select statement to get the total number of rows and add that to your main SELECT statement.

```
SELECT data AS data, count.count
FROM data 
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(data)) AS count FROM data WHERE parameter = "test") AS count
WHERE parameter = "test"
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1;
```

[Here's a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58dab/1)

Answer (score 1):

I think this situation needs to be split in two steps:

1. Select the random entry where `param` has the value you want
2. Count the entries of the data

I propose this solution

```
set @yourParam = 1; -- Put here the parameter value you want to filter
select 
    data, 
    (select count(distinct date) from data_table where param=@yourParam) as `count`
from 
    data_table
where 
    param = @yourParam
order by 
    rand()
limit 1;
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select 
     data, (select count(distinct data) from data_table where param=1) as `count`
from 
   data_table  where param = 1
order by rand()
limit 1
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f66c/10)